# Windows restores service running state on startup

Tags: windows, services

I'm having this weird issue that's driving me up the wall. I have Apache and MySQL installed as services on a Windows dev machine. They are both configured on manual startup. If they are running and I perform a **shutdown**, on the next power on they are back in running state. If I perform a **restart** they are not running anymore, as it should be. This is happening consistently on every power on / reboot.

Anyone knows what's the catch and how can I disable this crazy behavior? Manual startup should be manual, no matter what.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fast startup? Have you tried disabling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a difference what version of Windows you are running. 
In Windows 10, when you tell it to shut down, it actually just goes to sleep,
so the services aren’t “back” up, they are ***still*** up.

Comment: Sorry, it's Windows 10, up to date, and it does shut down, it's a desktop, I shut it down through Start Menu's "Shut down" option.

Comment: Wow, that got me thinking, so I scoured the web. Here's what I got: https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

Thanks Scott, you made my day. My week, actually. I did not imagine it's a feature.